# Pass in jQuery/plainJS variables/functions of a current scope to anonymous function called from current scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

How to pass current scope variables and functions to the anonymous function in plain Javascript or in jQuery (if it's  specific for frameworks).

For example:

```
jQuery.extend({
  someFunction: function(onSomeEvent) {
    var variable = 'some text'
    onSomeEvent.apply(this); // how to pass current scope variables/functions to this function?
    return null;

    _someMethod(arg) {
      console.log(arg);
    }
  }
});
```

Should log in firebug everything from the function above:

```
jQuery.someFunction(function(){
  console.log(this.variable); // or console.log(variable);
  console.log(this._someMethod(1); // or jQuery.someFunction._someMethod(2);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about Scopes in JavaScript for example in "Java Script: The good parts".

In the Java Script there is only scope inside Functions.
If you specify your variable inside function with **var** you can't access them from outside of this function. This is way to make private variables in JavaScript.

You can use **this** variable, that point to current object you are in (this is not a scope itself). But! if you initiate function without **new** command, than **this** will point to outer scope (in most cases it's window object = global scope).

Example:

```
function foo(){
  var a = 10;
}
var f = foo(); //there is nothing in f
var f = new foo(); //there is nothing in f

function bar(){
  this.a = 10;
}
var b = new bar(); //b.a == 10
var b = bar(); //b.a == undefined, but a in global scope
```

Btw, check out syntax of apply method [Mozilla docs/apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
So you can see, that fist argument is object, that will be **this** when your method will be called.

So consider this example:

```
function bar(){ 
  console.log(this.a);
  console.log(this.innerMethod(10)); 
}

function foo(){ 
  this.a = 10;
  this.innerMethod = function(a){
     return a+10;
  }

  bar.apply(this); 
}

var f = new foo(); // => you will get 10 and 20 in the console.
var f = foo(); // => you will still get 10 and 20 in the console. But in this case, your "this" variable //will be just a global object (window)
```

Maybe it's better to make

```
var that = this;
```

before calling apply method, but maybe it's not needed. not sure

So, this definitely will work:

```
function foo(){
  console.log(this.a);
}
jQuery.extend({
 somefunc: function(func){
   this.a = 10;
   func.apply(this);
 }
});

$.somefunc(foo); //will print 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before line 1:

```
var that = this;
```

Then change line 4:

```
onSomeEvent.apply(that);
```

Comment: And how to call functions and variables? Using this.variable?

Comment: Simplefied: (function(){var _this = this;var a = 2;console.log(_this.a);})(); - how to get a variable from another variable, hash or I don't know what else...